# Removing Outer Bracket and Naming object with number?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I got really confusing with json ( I still learning about json ).

the JSON I want to:

```
{  "entityMap": {
    "0": {
      "type": "LINK",
      "mutability": "MUTABLE",
      "data": {
        "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "type": "LINK",
      "mutability": "MUTABLE",
      "data": {
        "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "type": "LINK",
      "mutability": "MUTABLE",
      "data": {
        "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
      }
    },
    "3": {
      "type": "LINK",
      "mutability": "MUTABLE",
      "data": {
        "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is that considered bad json? And how to naming json with number like that?

This by far what I got.

```
{
    "entityMap": [
        {
            "type": "LINK",
            "mutability": "MUTABLE",
            "data": {
                "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "LINK",
            "mutability": "MUTABLE",
            "data": {
                "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "LINK",
            "mutability": "MUTABLE",
            "data": {
                "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

this my class

```
    public class editorRawTest
    {
        public List<entityMapItem> entityMap { get; set; }

    }


    public class entityMapItem
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string mutability { get; set; }
        public entityMapItemData data { get; set; }
    }

    public class entityMapItemData
    {
        public string url { get; set; }

    }
```

my execute code:

```
                var map = new List<entityMapItem>();

                var mapitem = new entityMapItem() { type = "LINK", mutability = "MUTABLE", data = new entityMapItemData() { url = "https://stackoverflow.com/" }  };

                map.Add(mapitem);
                map.Add(mapitem);
                map.Add(mapitem);



                editorRawTest bc = new editorRawTest() { entityMap = map };

                string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bc);
                string path = @"jsonmapdata.json";
                using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
                {
                    tw.WriteLine(JSONresult.ToString());
                    tw.Close();
                }
```

Searching through google and stackoverflow with no luck. 
Any clue or help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: i think, the first json is bad, why you need to add number of any object. you can use just use array like the second json?

Comment: What is the actual question? `The JSON I want to <JSON>` doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first JSON, you would need to replace your `List<entityMapItem>` with a `Dictionary<string, entityMapItem>`, like this:

```
public class editorRawTest
{
    public Dictionary<string, entityMapItem> entityMap { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would need to fill it like this:

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, entityMapItem>();

var mapitem = new entityMapItem() { type = "LINK", mutability = "MUTABLE", data = new entityMapItemData() { url = "https://stackoverflow.com/" }  };

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    map.Add(i.ToString(), mapitem);
}
```

But I would discourage you from doing that unless you have to.  What you have now (the second JSON with the list) is much easier to work with.  If you have a choice between the two, it is better to choose the second approach.  See [Using json key to store value, is it a good approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53655587/10263) for why.

Comment: I dont know sir, but its code legacy from former programmer. In my personal opinion , I like the second one but the "others" maybe not like it. So I didnt have choice but stick together with first one.

Comment: That's fine; if you don't have a choice, then there's nothing to debate.  (I wasn't sure from your question whether you were designing something new or just trying to work with existing JSON.)

Comment: Iam work with existing json. Sorry about the question, I have limited capability with english, so I confused how to speak what in my mind. But thanks for helps, I really appreciated it, Usually I use verbatim string, but now I tried to use json.net ( keeping me sane )